# Syllabus in LaTeX

Tags: templates, examples

I need to produce a syllabus for a course I'm going to teach at the University. Could you suggest me any example (or template) of a well-designed syllabus in LaTeX? Are there any useful packages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I write my course syllabi in LaTeX ([here's an example](http://www.kieranhealy.org/files/teaching/gradtheory.pdf)), but I don't think a specialized template is really necessary: the basic machinery of sections, subsections and lists does the job pretty well, I find.

Comment: Perhaps a more specific request would be easier to handle. What do you want your syllabus to look like? Why isn't plain LaTeX sections, lists, descriptions and so on enough?

Comment: @Seamus They are more than enough! I'm just looking for some nice looking templates! The example linked by Kieran is very appealing.

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/843/latex-classes-or-styles-for-schedules-and-or-calendars

Comment: @Kieran very pretty syllabus there.  any chance you can share the corresponding .tex file?

Comment: @Kieran I second dbliss 's request! Absolutely beautiful template!

Comment: Nevermind— I found @Kieran 's files on his github— thank you so much for providing this! https://github.com/kjhealy/latex-custom-kjh

Comment: Glad people like it. Yes, the latex style files and .tex templates are here: https://github.com/kjhealy/latex-custom-kjh, and if you write in markdown/use pandoc then these might also be of interest: https://github.com/kjhealy/pandoc-templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `termcal` package is very useful for dealing with the schedule of a syllabus, especially if you teach a course regularly or have multiple sections of a course. It generates a calendar for the course based on a starting date. Other than that, I don't think there's much need for anything more than regular sectioning commands (as others have mentioned).

Comment: [Termcal link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/termcal/), if you can't be bothered googling it yourself.

Comment: @Seamus Why google when `texdoc` will do the same?

Answer (score 4):

I would not think a syllabus needs any eye-candy design, so a simple LaTeX document would do the task.

I have found two templates thought worth to mention, the first from the [University of Connecticut](http://www.math.uconn.edu/TANet/Teaching/teaching.php) and the other one from [Matt Mastin](http://sites.google.com/site/mattmastin/teaching/grsc-7700/latex-templates). I hope you could use these and good luck designing, customizing your own syllabus template!

Comment: uconn link is dead.

Comment: Thanks, @dbliss. The Math TA Network seems to still have the LaTeX template at http://www.math.uconn.edu/tanetwork/teaching-info

Comment: All three links above are now dead.