# How to mod a counter's value?

Tags: counters

I think [Custom calendar using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/custom-calendar-using-tikz) is useful!

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: I suspect that the one sentence "question" is speculating broadly about a potential solution to the problem stated in the title. If Bob Bull returns to verify this, hopefully he can verify this, and then we can revise the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18813/modular-arithmetic-in-latex

Comment: The question is now closed because it is incomprehensible. You can rewrite it, so that we know what you want to ask. If you do that, flag for a moderator to reopen the question (use `flag` below the question).

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{intcalc}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{5}
\intcalcMod{\themycounter}{2} % =1
```