# Making a list with dates for labels, automatically skipping days

Tags: lists, datetime

I'm making my first syllabus in LaTeX and would like to know if there is a LaTeX-y way to generate the course schedule. Something like:

> 7/5 Friday: Read blah
>
> 7/8 Monday: Blah
>
> 7/10 Wednesday: Blah
>
> 7/12 Friday: Blah

The course is Monday-Wednesday-Friday, so I'm looking for a way to generate a list that will skip Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday and Sunday.

I realize that simply manually editing the labels to reflect the dates would be easy enough, there are only 40 or so class meetings, but is there a way (package or native commands I'm unfamiliar with) to do this in a more automated way? Especially because it would make using this syllabus as a template for future syllabi much easier.

Comment: Does the following help: [LaTeX Classes or Styles for Schedules and/or Calendars?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/843/latex-classes-or-styles-for-schedules-and-or-calendars) or [Syllabus in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10158/syllabus-in-latex)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I looked at both, sadly I didn't see anything that helps here. I'm not looking for a full-on calendar graphic, just a list of class dates and required readings--- keeping it minimal.

Comment: Related: [How to create Page-a-Day Calendar Template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39972/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate,datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{advdate,datetime}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\par\longdate\renewcommand{\item}{\par%
    \stepcounter{mycntr}\ifnum\value{mycntr}>3\relax%
      \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]%
    \else
      \AdvanceDate[2]%
    \fi\today\quad}
  }{\par}
\newcounter{mycntr}
\begin{document}
\begin{schedule}
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Relax
  \item Go to the sea
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Relax
  \item Go to the sea
\end{schedule}
\end{document}
```

It would be possible to adjust the alignment as well as a starting date via an optional argument (say).

Comment: I posted [another follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122807/inserting-day-of-the-week-into-custom-datetime-format) to this. If you knew of a quick fix to that problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which I upvoted. However, at the end, you say that it is possible to adjust the starting date. How can this be done ? Thank you!

Comment: @Watson: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/7G2JVHAi). It allows for an optional argument to `schedule` where you can update any combination of the registers `\year`, `\month` and `\day` to suit your needs (don't use commas `,` to separate the setting of registers). This updates `\today` that is used in the calculation. It assumes the new date will be a Monday, since it still skips Tuesdays, Thursdays and the weekend (Saturday, Sunday).

Comment: Dear @Werner, thank you very much for your helpful comment. My final version for this part of the code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/th1hYPau).