# Filling Table Automatic with Dates and Daynames

Tags: tables, calendar

I am trying to create a latex document containing a 3 column table where the first column should contain the date and the name of a day between 01.01.2020 till 31.12.2020 and the other two columns should be free to be filled out by hand on the printout. Each page should contain one month. If possible the weekends should be highlightes with color across the whole line.

Is it possible to have latex do that automatically so i just have to change the year when I need the 2021 file?

I am aware that this would be trivial with excel but I want to give latex a try.

Comment: Could you post a `MWE` on what you have tried so far?

Comment: right now i have not tried anything, because i have not the slightest idea where to start. sure i could create a table and fill in the dates an names by hand, but i have not the slightest idea if and how to "automate" the table.

Comment: Might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables and

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is too broad to be covered in a single answer. It is better to break your question in to multiple parts and ask them one-by-one instead. Thereby, it will be easy to answer small increments than creating all at once in `do it for me` fashion.

Comment: Maybe section `47 Calendar Library` of the pgfmanual can be of use here.

Comment: @marmot I will look into that, indeed on first look, offers great possibilities. But, I am not sure, how much I could exploit ;)

Answer (score 2):

A starting point could be by defining a small macro and a loop along with `advdate` and `datetime` packages as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\newcount\fooo
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
% some help from this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122807/inserting-day-of-the-week-into-custom-datetime-format
% some help from that
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122785/making-a-list-with-dates-for-labels-automatically-skipping-days
    \SetDate[01/01/2020]
    \newcounter{mycntr}
    \begin{document}
    \def\tabledata{} \fooo=365
    \loop
   \addto\tabledata{\AdvanceDate[\value{mycntr}]\today\stepcounter{mycntr} &  & \\
    \hline}
    \advance \fooo -1
    \ifnum \fooo>0
    \repeat 

    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \tabledata
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This spit-outs more than `10 pages`, hence, I wouldn't dare to post a screenshot of them ;)

**Open-issue:** Breaking the page based on the end of month. I don't yet know how to achieve it.

However, on the other hand, the OP can break the table manually by defining the `SetDate` and `\fooo` counter for every month followed by a `\newpage` command (which, might make life simpler, imho).

Comment: @marmot no probs ;)