# Using loops to create tables

Tags: tables, loops

The goal is to create the following table  without having to typeset all the rows one after another but using some kind of  loops like  the `\foreach` command provided by the `pgffor` package

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,pgffor}
\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.5pt}}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}\toprule
  \(i\) & \(m\) & \(P\)  & \(y_{m}\) \\\midrule
  1&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule& \myhrule\\
  2&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule& \myhrule\\
  3&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule&\myhrule\\
  4&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule&\myhrule\\
  5&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule&\myhrule\\
  6&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule& \myhrule\\
  7&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule& \myhrule\\
  8&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule&\myhrule\\
  9&  \myhrule   &  \myhrule&\myhrule\\\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\noindent
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}{\i \hspace{1cm} \myhrule \hspace{1cm} \myhrule\hspace{1cm} \myhrule \\}

%or 

\noindent
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}{\i \foreach \j in {1,...,3} {\hspace{1cm} \myhrule}\\}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175573/118739

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367988/124577

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution with `pgfplotstable`.

I've created a table of the desired number of rows from scratch with `\pgfplotstablenew` and then display it with `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

The column styles set with `\pgfplotstableset` are fully customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,pgffor}
\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.5pt}}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
%set the columns style and content
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/new/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}},
    columns/new/.style={column name={\(i\)},column type={p{0.5cm}}},
    create on use/emme/.style={create col/set={\myhrule}},
    columns/emme/.style={column name={\(m\)},string type, column type={>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}},
    create on use/pi/.style={create col/copy={emme}},
    columns/pi/.style={column name={\(P\)},string type, column type={>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}},
    create on use/yup/.style={create col/copy={emme}},
    columns/yup/.style={column name={\(y_{m}\)},string type, column type={>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}},
    }
%create a table with the desidered number of rows
\pgfplotstablenew[
    columns={new, emme, pi, yup}
    ]{9}% <--- put here the number of rows you like
    \loadedtable
%display the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    ]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based answer. No need for the `pgffor` package.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.5pt}}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function print_line (i)
  tex.sprint(i.."&\\myhrule&\\myhrule&\\myhrule\\\\")
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.5cm} *{3}{C{2cm}} @{}}
\toprule
\(i\) & \(m\) & \(P\)  & \(y_{m}\) \\
\midrule
\directlua{ for i = 1 , 10 do print_line ( i ) end }
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Suppose you wanted to generalize the Lua code so that it prints `J` rather than always `3` copies of `&\\myhrule` before forcing a line break. Assuming that `J=5`, say, all you'd have to do is (a) replace

```
function print_line (i)
  tex.sprint(i.."&\\myhrule&\\myhrule&\\myhrule\\\\")
end
```

with

```
function print_line (i,J)
  tex.sprint(i)
  for j=1,J do tex.sprint("&\\myhrule") end
  tex.sprint("\\\\")
end
```

and (b) change the function call

```
print_line ( i )
```

to

```
print_line ( i , 5)
```

in the argument of the subsequent `\directlua` directive in the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Thank you for your rely. It seems straightforward and elegant with LuaLaTeX. I use to compile with pdfLaTeX. Is there a difference in the output between the two engines?

Comment: Assuming you have a reasonably up to date TeX distribution, any differences between the outputs produced by the two engines should be *very minor* much of the time. LuaTeX does use a different approach to paragraph building; *in principle*, there *could* be differences in line breaks and hyphenations. In my own work, though, I have yet to come across a practical instance of different line breaks. See the posting [Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/5001) and the links therein for a discussion of how to go about switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

First implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeruledtabular}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of rows, #2 = header
  \begin{tabular}{r w{c}{2cm} w{c}{2cm} @{}}
  \toprule
  #2 \\
  \midrule
  \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n
 {
  #1 & \myhrule & \myhrule \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeruledtabular{10}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(i\)} & \(P\) & \(y_{m}\) }

\end{document}
```

[image]

More general implementation: the number of columns is determined from the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeruledtabular}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of rows, #2 = header
  \hafid_ruledtabular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq
\tl_new:N \l__hafid_ruledtabular_first_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hafid_ruledtabular:nn
 {
  % absorb the header as a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq { & } { #2 }
  % split off the first item, which should be centered
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq \l__hafid_ruledtabular_first_tl
  % Define the auxiliary function based on the number of items in the header
  % At the end, if the header is 'A & B & C & D`, the function will be
  % defined to do '#1 & \myhrule & \myhrule & \myhrule \\', where #1 stands
  % for the current index in the loop
  \cs_set_protected:Nx \__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n
   {
    ##1
    \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq }
     { & \exp_not:N \myhrule }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    r
    *{ \seq_count:N \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq } { w{c}{2cm} }
    @{}
   }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tl_use:N \l__hafid_ruledtabular_first_tl} &
  \seq_use:Nn \l__hafid_ruledtabular_header_seq { & } \\
  \midrule
  \int_step_function:nN {#1} \__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\makeruledtabular{10}{\(i\) & \(P\) & \(y_{m}\) }

\bigskip

\makeruledtabular{15}{A & B & C & D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is that loop of the form `..._function:...` will deliver the whole loop before anything else is processed, so in the case of a three column table with three rows we will get

```
\__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n { 1 }
\__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n { 2 }
\__hafid_ruledtabular_line:n { 3 }
```

and only after this TeX will start to process the first item, therefore getting

```
1 & \myhrule & \myhrule \\
2 & \myhrule & \myhrule \\
3 & \myhrule & \myhrule \\
```

yielding the full table body.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have some troubles with the LaTeX3 syntax I am still with LaTeX2e. I should make the jump but it is not easy for me.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda I added some comments to the second implementation.

Comment: @egreg How can I make a long table contains 200 rows?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 You have to use `longtable` instead of `tabular`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this (updated based on `@Mico's` comments):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,booktabs}
\newcount\fooo
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
%some help from here
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472554/filling-table-automatic-with-dates-and-daynames/472561#472561
\newcommand{\myhrule}{\rule{1cm}{0.5pt}}
    \newcounter{mycntr}
    \setcounter{mycntr}{1}
    \begin{document}
    \def\tabledata{} \fooo=30
    \loop
   \addto\tabledata{\themycntr\stepcounter{mycntr} &\myhrule  &\myhrule &\myhrule\\}
    \advance \fooo -1
    \ifnum \fooo>0
    \repeat 

    \begin{longtable}{cccc}
        \toprule
        $i$&$m$&$p$&$y_m$\\
        \midrule
        \tabledata
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

Comment: The OP seems commendably averse to using vertical rules in the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the remark. I adapted this from my past answer. I will incorporate your comments once I'm back home `;-)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I wonder if there is a way the replace the `\loop` block in your code  with a `\foreach` block?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda then, afaik, you must use `pgf` package. I'm not sure we can use that here. But I will note it as well atop `Mico's` comments.

Comment: @Raaja - Now you seem to have replaced the triplets of `\myhrule` in each row with `\hline`.

Comment: @Mico I only removed the vertical rules, I haven't changed anything else. Could you tell me what is `\myhrule`?

Comment: @Raaja - Please check the OP's code; that's where `\myhrule` is defined.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the clarification:), oooh, I didn't notice it. I will incorporate that.

Comment: @Mico Updated my answer with the `myhrule` triplets.