# Template for class schedule?

Tags: tables

Does anyone have a good template for a class schedule? I want something like this: [image]

But I want to make it on LaTeX.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd like to make it in LaTeX rather than in, for example, Excel? Just curious.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX and am really enjoy using it and am trying to practice making things in it. I wanted to try it in LaTeX before I give up and go to Excel lol

Comment: Gotcha. Definitely have to agree with that

Comment: There is a `schedule` package at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/schedule?lang=en) that may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

From the [website LatexTemplatesDotCom](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/weekly-timetable) you can get the `calendar.sty` file included in the zip file, which in turn you can download clicking the "Download .zip button". This is an extract from the code available at the same link:

```
% Original calendar style author:
% Evan Sultanik (http://www.sultanik.com/LaTeX_calendar_style)
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% Important note:
% This template requires the calendar.sty file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The calendar.sty file provides the necessary structure to create the
% calendar.
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calendar} % Use the calendar.sty style
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes the page number from the bottom of the page
\noindent
\StartingDayNumber=1 % Calendar starting day, default of 1 means Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc
\begin{center}
\textsc{\LARGE Title}\\ % Title text
\textsc{\large Subtitle} % Subtitle text
\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{calendar}{\hsize}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIRST DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{\textbf{9am-5pm} \daysep Work at McDonald's} % By default all daily events are centered in the box, in order to bring them up use \vspace{2cm} after the event text; you may need to change the 2cm

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECOND DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{
\textbf{9am-10am} \daysep BIOSCI101 - BLT100 \\[3pt]
\textbf{10am-11am} \daysep BIOSCI 104 - LLT \\[3pt]
%\textbf{11am-12pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{12pm-1pm} \daysep BIOSCI105 - BLT204 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{1pm-2pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{2pm-5pm} \daysep BIOSCI101 Laboratory \\[3pt]
%\textbf{3pm-4pm} \daysep BIOSCI101 Laboratory \\[3pt]
%\textbf{4pm-5pm} \daysep BIOSCI101 Laboratory
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THIRD DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{ % Tuesday
\textbf{9am-10am} \daysep BIOSCI101 - BLT100 \\[3pt]
\textbf{10am-11am} \daysep BIOSCI 104 - LLT \\[3pt]
%\textbf{11am-12pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{12pm-1pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{1pm-2pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{2pm-3pm} \daysep GEO101 - HSB1 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{3pm-4pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{4pm-5pm} \daysep No Lecture
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FOURTH DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{ % Wednesday
%\textbf{9am-10am} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{10am-11am} \daysep BIOSCI 104 - LLT \\[3pt]
%\textbf{11am-12pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{12pm-1pm} \daysep BIOSCI105 - BLT204 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{1pm-2pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{2pm-3pm} \daysep GEO101 - HSB1 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{3pm-4pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{4pm-5pm} \daysep No Lecture
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIFTH DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{ % Thursday
%\textbf{9am-10am} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{10am-11am} \daysep BIOSCI 104 - LLT \\[3pt]
%\textbf{11am-12pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{12pm-1pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{1pm-2pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{2pm-3pm} \daysep GEO101 - HSB1 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{3pm-4pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{4pm-5pm} \daysep No Lecture
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIXTH DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{ % Friday
\textbf{9am-10am} \daysep BIOSCI101 - BLT100 \\[3pt]
\textbf{10am-11am} \daysep BIOSCI 104 - LLT \\[3pt]
%\textbf{11am-12pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{12pm-1pm} \daysep BIOSCI105 - BLT204 \\[3pt]
%\textbf{1pm-2pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
%\textbf{2pm-3pm} \daysep No Lecture \\[3pt]
\textbf{3pm-4pm} \daysep GEO101 Tutorial \\ Room A \\[3pt]
%\textbf{4pm-5pm} \daysep No Lecture
} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SEVENTH DAY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\day{}{} % Saturday

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\finishCalendar
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

You can also take a look at the TeXSE post [Schedule in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/schedule-in-latex) .

Edit: Thanks to [Stefan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow) for pointing out the previous flaws. I also added where specifically you can get the calendar.sty file

Comment: Where do you find `calendar.sty`? It would be better if you showed that you have actually answered the question as distinct from just supplying a similar style file and a potentially useful link...

Comment: @Andrew Is in the reference at the start of the answer: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/weekly-timetable