# How to translate tikz calendar names?

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, calendar

TikZ-calendar uses English names like Monday, Mon, Tuesday, January, February etc. How to I automatically translate them to - say - German?

Looking at the `pgfcalendar.code.tex` file I see all those names wrapped in a `\translate` command. I assume that this is somehow related to the babel package?

I include babel and tikz like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% [..]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
% [..]
```

Should that be enough such that babel automatically picks up and translates all the TikZ-calendar names?

Perhaps there are missing some babel/TikZ language files? Is there is something to lookout for?

I am using the texlive-* packages under Fedora 19 - and I have installed some german language packages like texlive-babel-german and texlive-collection-langgerman - and currently the calendar names are **not** translated.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144160/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `\translate` command is from the `translator` package which comes (I think) with the `beamer` class. In order to get translations you must load `babel` *first*, followed by the `translator` package and *before* the `tikz` package and the `calendar` library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german]{translator}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\scriptsize
\tikz
  \calendar [dates=2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31,
    month list,month label left,month yshift=1.25em]
    if (Sunday) [black!50];

\end{document}
```

(the picture shown here is only part of the resulting `pdf`)

[image]

Comment: Do you know by any chance which files this depends on so that somebody could configure things to support a language for which the translations don't exist? Actually, I think tlmgr info --list beamer | grep English gives this information.