# translate tikz calendar names to persian?

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, tikz-calendar

I see the quastion [How to translate tikz calendar names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150857/how-to-translate-tikz-calendar-names) and I try to make farsi calendar wti this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[farsi]{babel}
\usepackage[farsi]{translator}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\scriptsize
\tikz
  \calendar [dates=2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31,
    month list,month label left,month yshift=1.25em]
    if (Sunday) [black!50];

\end{document}
```

like that quastion but it shows me below error:
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown.
! LaTeX Error: Command \alefhamza unavailable in encoding OT1.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option`farsi' for package `translator'.
! LaTeX Error: Font family`LAE+cmss' unknown.

what can I do ?
tanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think there is no `farsi` dictionary for translator, you'll need to build it.

Comment: tank you for your attention. Can you explain a bit how can I build?

Comment: To create persian calendar you can use `xepersian-pst-calendar.sty` from the `xepersian` package over XeLaTeX , you can take a look  [here](http://code.openhub.net/project?pid=&ipid=175901&fp=175901&mp&projSelected=true&filterChecked)

Comment: tanks alot for your attention. but I am beginner. I want a simple way. or simple manual. Can you explain? my final goal is to use it in gantt chart can I try with this? tkank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Farsi, but one of my languages is not supported out-of-the-box by the `translator` package. It's a shame `calendar` can't use Babel directly, since the language definition files include month names and are available for a wider variety of languages. But it is not difficult to cook-up your own.

You need to find `translator-months-dictionary-English.dict` and copy it into your working directory as `translator-months-dictionary-Farsi.dict`. On Linux, for Welsh, you could use

```
cp $(kpsewhich translator-months-dictionary-English.dict) ./translator-months-dictionary-Welsh.dict
```

Just use whatever method you usually use to find, copy and rename files. The `.dict` file is part of the `translator` now and this is no longer part of Beamer, but a standalone package.

Open the renamed file in your text editor and replace the Welsh words and abbreviations with Farsi translations of the English. Change the word `Welsh` at the top to `Farsi`.

```
\ProvidesDictionary{translator-months-dictionary}{Welsh}

\providetranslation{January}{Ionawr}
\providetranslation{February}{Chwefror}
\providetranslation{March}{Mawrth}
\providetranslation{April}{Ebrill}
\providetranslation{May}{Mai}
\providetranslation{June}{Mehefin}
\providetranslation{July}{Gorffennaf}
\providetranslation{August}{Awst}
\providetranslation{September}{Medi}
\providetranslation{October}{Hydref}
\providetranslation{November}{Tachwedd}
\providetranslation{December}{Rhagfyr}

\providetranslation{Jan}{Ion}
\providetranslation{Feb}{Chwe}
\providetranslation{Mar}{Maw}
\providetranslation{Apr}{Ebr}
\providetranslation{May}{Mai}
\providetranslation{Jun}{Meh}
\providetranslation{Jul}{Gorff}
\providetranslation{Aug}{Awst}
\providetranslation{Sep}{Medi}
\providetranslation{Oct}{Hyd}
\providetranslation{Nov}{Tach}
\providetranslation{Dec}{Rhag}

\providetranslation{Monday}{Llun}
\providetranslation{Tuesday}{Mawrth}
\providetranslation{Wednesday}{Mercher}
\providetranslation{Thursday}{Iau}
\providetranslation{Friday}{Gwener}
\providetranslation{Saturday}{Sadwrn}
\providetranslation{Sunday}{Sul}

\providetranslation{Mon}{Llun}
\providetranslation{Tue}{Maw}
\providetranslation{Wed}{Mer}
\providetranslation{Thu}{Iau}
\providetranslation{Fri}{Gwe}
\providetranslation{Sat}{Sad}
\providetranslation{Sun}{Sul}
```

That is, the bits which aren't English should be Farsi and the word `Welsh`, which is English, should be `Farsi`.

I then used

```
\documentclass[welsh]{standalone}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\scriptsize
\tikz
  \calendar [dates=2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31,
    month list,month label left,month yshift=1.25em]
    if (Sunday) [black!50];

\end{document}
```

with the result

[image: Welsh calendar]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `month text=\ifcase\the\numexpr\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-1 translationofJan\or translationofFeb ...\or translationofDec\fi` in the calendar option lists.