# Tikz calendar in spanish

Tags: calendar, spanish, translator

I've found [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/a-calender-for-doublesided-din-a4/) and I'm trying to arrange the template to this year, my language and my country. My question is how can I get the days and months in Spanish. I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144160/using-tikz-calendar-in-portuguese-as-a-syllabus?rq=1) in stackexchange, and and I've tried to apply the manner stated to rename the days and months, without success.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,spanish,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}           
\usepackage[spanish]{translator}    

\deftranslation[to=spanish]{January}{Enero}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{February}{Febrero}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{March}{Marzo}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{April}{Abril}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{May}{Mayo}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{June}{Junio}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{July}{Julio}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{August}{Agosto}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{September}{Septiembre}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{October}{Octubre}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{November}{Noviembre}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{December}{Diciembre}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Mon}{Lun}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Tue}{Mar}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Wed}{Mié}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Thu}{Jue}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Fri}{Vie}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Sat}{Sab}
\deftranslation[to=spanish]{Sun}{Dom}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       
\usepackage{fix-cm}     
\usepackage[landscape, headheight = 2cm, margin=.5cm,top = 3.2cm, nofoot]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\def\year{2015}
\def\termin#1#2{
\node [anchor=north west, text width= 3.4cm] at
($(cal-#1.north west)+(3em, 0em)$) {\tiny{#2}};
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{10ex}
\chead{
\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont\textbf{\year}
\Large\textbf{Calendario}\hfill
}
\cfoot{\footnotesize\texttt{http://www.texample.net/}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every day/.style={anchor = north}]
\calendar[
dates=\year-01-01 to \year-06-30,%primera hoja, desde Enero a Junio
name=cal,
day yshift = 3em,
day code=
{
\node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,every day,shape=rectangle,
minimum height= .53cm, text width = 4.4cm, draw = gray]{\tikzdaytext};
\draw (-1.8cm, -.1ex) node[anchor = west]{\footnotesize%
  \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
},
execute before day scope=
{
\ifdate{day of month=1}
{
  \pgftransformxshift{4.8cm}
  % Print month name
  \draw (0,0)node [shape=rectangle, minimum height= .53cm,
    text width = 4.4cm, fill = red, text= white, draw = red, text centered]
    {\textbf{\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}}};
}{}
\ifdate{workday}
{
  \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=white}}
  \ifdate{between=2014-12-24 and 2015-03-06}{%
    \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
}{}
\ifdate{Saturday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
\ifdate{Sunday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=01-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=05-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=05-21}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=2015-04-03}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=2015-04-04}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=2015-06-29}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
},
 execute at begin day scope=
 {
\pgftransformyshift{-.53*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}
 }
];
\termin{\year-01-01}{Año Nuevo}
\termin{2015-04-03}{Viernes Santo}
\termin{2015-04-04}{Sábado Santo}
\termin{2015-04-05}{Domingo de Resurrección}
\termin{\year-05-01}{Día del Trabajo}
\termin{\year-05-21}{Combate Naval de Iquique}
\termin{2015-06-29}{San Pedro y San Pablo}
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagebreak
\begin{tikzpicture}[every day/.style={anchor = north}]
\calendar[
dates=\year-07-01 to \year-12-31,
name=cal,
day yshift = 3em,
day code=
{
\node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,every day,shape=rectangle,
  minimum height= .53cm, text width = 4.4cm, draw = gray]{\tikzdaytext};
\draw (-1.8cm, -.1ex) node[anchor = west]
{
  \footnotesize\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}
};
},
execute before day scope=
{
\ifdate{day of month=1} {
\pgftransformxshift{4.8cm}
\draw (0,0)node [shape=rectangle, minimum height= .53cm,
  text width = 4.4cm, fill = red, text= white, draw = red, text centered]
{
  \textbf{\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}}
 };
}{}
\ifdate{workday}
{
\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=white}}
\ifdate{between=2015-07-13 and 2015-07-26}{%
  \tikzset{every day/.style={fill=gray!30}}}{}
}{}
\ifdate{Saturday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!10}}}{}
\ifdate{Sunday}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=09-18}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=09-19}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=10-12}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=09-18}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=09-19}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=10-12}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=07-16}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=08-15}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=10-31}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=11-01}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=12-08}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
\ifdate{equals=12-25}{\tikzset{every day/.style={fill=red!20}}}{}
},
execute at begin day scope=
{
\pgftransformyshift{-.53*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}
}
];
\termin{\year-07-16}{Nuestra Señora del Carmen}
\termin{\year-08-15}{Asunción de la Virgen}
\termin{\year-09-18}{Fiestas Patrias}
\termin{\year-09-19}{Día del Ejército}
\termin{2015-10-12}{Encuentro de dos Mundos}
\termin{\year-10-31}{Día de las Iglesias Evangélicas}
\termin{\year-11-01}{Día de Todos los Santos}
\termin{\year-12-08}{Inmaculada Concepción}
\termin{\year-12-25}{Navidad del Señor}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and when compiling, you get:

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me if I change `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: No errors at compile time, only two warnings concerning the fancyhdr package. 
When using utf8, the following error is obtained: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \X not set up for use with LaTeX`, where "X" is any word with diacritical sign or tilde (ñ). When using latin1, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: It works fine for me, both with `latin1` and `utf8` encodings.

Comment: So the first thing to do is update all your packages.

Comment: After updating the packages, the language problem was solved, without using the `\deftranslation`. Thanks, John.