# Pgfgantt remove labels of month

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

My project has a 6 years duration and I want to realise a Gantt chart still readable in the width of the A4 page, in portrait format.

[image]

I want to remove the labels (the numbers) in the month line of the Gantt chart, and just keep empty cells of the table in my `pgfgantt` chart.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{pgfgantt} 
      
\begin{document}
   
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, 
    vgrid={dotted,draw=none,draw=none}, %hgrid=true, 
    x unit=0.22cm,          % NOTE: width for a single month
    y unit chart = 0.6cm, bar height=0.6,
    y unit title = 0.5cm, title height=1,
    include title in canvas=false,
    time slot unit=month
    ]{2024-09}{2030-09}  %project duration

    % temporal marks
    \gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!30,draw=black}]{year} \\
    \gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!20,draw=black}]{month} \\
\end{ganttchart}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add a minimal example to the question? So that we can copy&paste and play with it? Help us to help you! Thanks!

Comment: You can probably simplify https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507490/pgfgantt-month-displayed-as-single-letter by using `\def\pgfcalendarmonthsingleletter#1{\relax}` or something similar.

Comment: Hi, your code is not compilable as-is: please complete it (document class, packages, begin and end{document}, etc.