# Wall calendar style sheet

Tags: calendar

I would like to create an annual wall calendar entirely in LaTeX but cannot find an appropriate style sheet.  I'd like a full page monthly figure environment, each month automatically listed, the days of the week across the top (Sunday, Monday, ...), numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) in each day cell, and small text or figure environments for each of the 365 days.  The paging should correspond to a typical hanging calendar, in which the large figure for each month is at the top and the next page with the corresponding month name and day blocks hangs beneath.  Ideally, the final .eps or .pdf can be printed out and bound directly, ready to hang on a wall.

Comment: Have you seen the package `wallcalendar` for lualatex?

Comment: Thanks.  Just checked.  Alas, none of the options permits a large *day* cell, where I can include some text (or even teeny graphics) and leave room for the user to hand write calendar events in the day cell.

Comment: This is an old question, but I have recently been in a similar situation. If you come across this question through a search: check out http://www.latextemplates.com/template/monthly-calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible with TikZ' `calendar` library.

There's some fine-tuning to do with the length and dimensions to fit it to the page.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin={1cm},noheadfoot]{geometry}
\renewcommand*\thepage{}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\tikzset{
  every weekday/.style={
    anchor=south west,
    black,
    name=weekday-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday,
    node contents=\%wt},
  weekday above/.style={
    if = {(day of month=1) [days={append after command={
          node [at={(\tikzlastnode.north west)},
                alias=@firstweekday,
                every weekday]}}]},
    if = {(day of month=2, day of month=3, day of month=4, day of month=5, day of month=6, day of month=7) [
          days={append after command={
          node [at={(@firstweekday.south west-|\tikzlastnode.south west)}, every weekday]}}]}},
  wall calendar/.style={
    week list, weekday above, day text=,
    day and weekday/.style={
      draw, outer sep=+0pt,
      minimum width=\linewidth/7,
      minimum height=\textheight/8},
    day xshift=\linewidth/7,
    day yshift=\textheight/8,
    every day label/.style={
      anchor=north east,
      font=\Large\itshape,
      node contents={\%d=},
      inner sep=.7em},
    every day/.append style={
      day and weekday,
      label={[every day label]north east:}
    },
    every weekday/.append style={
      day and weekday,
      minimum height=2em}
  }
}
\newcommand*\Year{2022}
\begin{document}\sffamily
\centering
\foreach \mon in {1,...,12}{%
  {\Huge \pgfcalendarmonthname{\mon}\par}
  {\huge \Year\par}
  \vspace{2em}
  \tikz\calendar[
    dates=\Year-0\mon-01 to \Year-0\mon-last,
    wall calendar,
  ];

\pagebreak}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow... thanks so much.  Better late than never!