# Changing the box positions does nothing

Tags: tikz-pgf

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \huge
    % January - 2023
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
        \def\daywidth{4cm}
        \def\dayheight{3cm}
        \def\boxsize{1.75ex}
        \def\boxsep{0.4ex}
        \def\upperpadding{1.5cm}
        \def\monthname{January}
        \def\year{2023}
        \def\startday{6} % Adjust this value to change the starting day of the week (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, etc.)
        \def\numdays{31} % Adjust this value based on the actual number of days in the month
        
        \def\daynames{{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"}}
        % \node[anchor=north west] at (0.5*\daywidth*\numdays,0.5*\dayheight) {\monthname \ \year};

        \foreach \day in {0,1,...,6} {
            \node[anchor=north west, minimum width=\daywidth, minimum height=\boxsize, text depth=\boxsep, align=center,draw] at (30+\daywidth*\day, -\upperpadding) {\pgfmathparse{\daynames[\day]}\pgfmathresult};
        }

        % draw the empty boxes for the days before the first day of the month
        \foreach \day in {1,...,\startday} {
            \node[anchor=north west, minimum width=\daywidth, minimum height=\dayheight, text depth=\boxsep, align=center, draw] at (30+\daywidth*\day-\daywidth, -\upperpadding-3*\boxsize) {};
        }

        \foreach \d in {1,...,\numdays} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{int((\d-1+\startday)/7)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{mod(\d-1+\startday,7)}

            \node[anchor=north west,minimum width=\daywidth,minimum height=\dayheight,draw] at (30+\dx*\daywidth,-\upperpadding-\dy*\dayheight- 3*\boxsize) {\d};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: screenshot of my pdf]

My question is **why changing the `\upperpadding` variable does nothing**. It does not give me an error. But it also does not change anything. Making it 0 or 20 does not matter. I believe the compiler is `latexmk`.

I am open to any other suggestions regarding this code. This is my first attempt. I may have overcomplicated things.

Comment: If you move *everything* to a new y-coordinate, the same tikzpicture will be produced and inserted as normal at the same location(at `\begin{tikzpicture}`) in the document. For `\upperpadding` to make sense, you need something that is not moved.

Comment: Every TikZ picture has its own coordinate system and crops it's content. The coordinates can only be used to place things in relation to their picture not others or the page. Except when `remember picture` and the special `current page` is used. Quick fix would be to use `\path(0,0);` to make the origin actually part of your picture. (Or just use `\vspace{\upperpadding}` before the TikZ picture.)

Comment: You might be interested in the [`calendar` library](https://tikz.dev/library-calender): [Q407675](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407675) and [many others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681724).

Answer (score 1):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \huge
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
        \def\daywidth{4cm}
        \def\dayheight{3cm}
        \def\boxsize{1.75ex}
        \def\boxsep{0.5ex}
        \def\upperpadding{2.6cm}
        \def\monthname{January}
        \def\year{2023}
        \def\startday{6} % Adjust this value to change the starting day of the week (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, etc.)
        \def\numdays{31} % Adjust this value based on the actual number of days in the month
        \def\daynames{{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"}}
        
        \node[anchor=north,align=center,font=\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont] at (0.5\textwidth,-1cm) {\monthname \ \year};

        \foreach \day in {0,1,...,6} {
            \node[anchor=north, minimum width=\daywidth, minimum height=\boxsize, text depth=\boxsep, align=center,draw] at (30+\daywidth*\day, -\upperpadding) {\pgfmathparse{\daynames[\day]}\pgfmathresult};
        }

        \foreach \day in {1,...,\startday} {
            \node[anchor=north, minimum width=\daywidth, minimum height=\dayheight, text depth=\boxsep, align=center, draw] at (30+\daywidth*\day-\daywidth, -\upperpadding-3*\boxsize) {};
        }

        \foreach \d in {1,...,\numdays} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{int((\d-1+\startday)/7)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{mod(\d-1+\startday,7)}

            \node[anchor=north,minimum width=\daywidth,minimum height=\dayheight,draw] at (30+\dx*\daywidth,-\upperpadding-\dy*\dayheight- 3*\boxsize) {\d};
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As [hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen) and [qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) pointed out the tikz picture needed another node