# is there a library to print blank calendars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I would like to be able to easily generate calendars like the following:

[image: example]

Is there some package or library to easily generate something like this, given the initial year and month?  TiKZ has a calendar library, but it does not generate the the desired layout.

Comment: Read this posting and try the code.  You can modify termcal to get what you want.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/843/latex-classes-or-styles-for-schedules-and-or-calendars