# Creating calendar for several months

Tags: calendar

I am looking into making a table for a semester that I can write my schedule on. I have tried various templates that are out there but none of them sets the dates and days automatically.  Is there a template where I just input year and it automatically picks the right dates/days.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Big list here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/843/latex-classes-or-styles-for-schedules-and-or-calendars

Comment: Are you aware of the `calendar` library that is described in section 47 of the pgfmanual? @KJO is mentioning some nice posts in their answer which got downvoted and deleted (and I do not understand why).

Comment: @marmot it may be the Gregorian calendar template was considered too old as it was from the Latex209 collection found here http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/#tools

Comment: @KJO Well, I am not sure this should earn one a downvote for that, but of course some users insist that votes do not have to be justified...